# How do I set label in h:selectOneListbox?

Tags: jsf, listbox, label

I have to display a list box with label as value "name" & I am using h:selectOneListbox.

My Code is :

```
<h:selectOneListbox id="select" value"#{trial.trials}" size="1" title="Select Item...">
<f:selectItems value="#{trial.trials}/>
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

My trial bean is :

```
public class trial{

List<trialDataBean> trials = new ArrayList<trialDataBean>();


public trial(){
trialDatBean tdb = new trialDataBean(1,"aatmiya");
trials.add(tdb);
}

public List<trialDataBean> getTrials(){
return trials;
}

public void setTrials() {
this.trials = trials;
}

}
```

trialDataBean has a property "name" & I want to set it as a label of the ListBox.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSF 1.x, you need to create a `List<SelectItem>` based on your `List<Trial>`. The constructor of [`SelectItem`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html) can take the option value as 1st argument and the option label as 2nd argument.

```
public class Bean {

    private Trial selectedTrial;
    private List<Trial> trials;
    private List<SelectItem> selectTrials;

    public Bean() {
        trials = loadItSomehow();
        selectTrials = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        for (Trial trial : trials) {
            selectTrials.add(new SelectItem(trial, trial.getName()));
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then you can use it in the view as follows:

```
<h:selectOneListbox value="#{bean.selectedTrial}" converter="trialConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.selectTrials}" />
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

You only need to supply a custom [`Converter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) which converts between `Trial` and `String`. More detail can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6850681).

---

In JSF 2.x, you can omit the `List<SelectItem>` and use the new `var` attribute in `f:selectItems` instead:

```
<h:selectOneListbox value="#{bean.selectedTrial}" converter="trialConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.trials}" var="trial"
        itemValue="#{trial}" itemLabel="#{trial.name}" />
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

Comment: Just switched from JSF1 to JSF2 and loving the new var attribute on h:selectOneListbox.

Comment: any idea if and how I can handle the double click on an item?

Comment: I am following what you (BalusC) have done for JSF 2 but when I inspect the element in chrome each of my options has the whole List as its value.

Here is my code:

Java
    private ConnectedUser connection_to_remove;
    private List<ConnectedUser> connected_users;

On form submit I want to remove the `connection_to_remove` from the `connected_users` List.

JSP:
    <h:selectOneListbox id="pName" value="#{userConnections.connection_to_remove}">

Comment: @edhedges: then you're not actually using JSF 2.x, or you're running JSF 2.x in JSF 1.x fallback modus due to bad configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this. I am not sure it will work or not because I have used `<ice:selectOneMenu>` tag and it worked perfectly.

```
<ice:selectOneListbox 
    id="paymnent" rows="10" tabindex="4"
    value="#{paymentVoucherReportAction.reportType}"
    style="width: 200px;height: 20px;">
    <f:selectItems id="AutoCmpTasdfasdfasdxtItms11"
        value="#{paymentVoucherReportAction.lstKeyValueData}" />
</ice:selectOneListbox>
```

// Bean(Action) File

```
    private List<SelectItem> lstKeyValueData = new ArrayList<SelectItem>(); // getter + setter

    private String reportType;  // getter + setter

    // put this in your init method

    List< SelectItem> list = new ArrayList< SelectItem>();

    list.add(new SelectItem("PDF Format","PDF Format"));

    list.add(new SelectItem("XLS Format","XLS Format"));

    setLstKeyValueData(list);

  // print this where you want

   System.out.println(reportType);
```