# JSF Add to selectOneMenu from a List<School>

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, glassfish-3, selectonemenu

I have a List object which hold School.Id, School.Name, and School.Address .

I need to list all the School.Name in a selectOneMenu List box. How will be the Java code and the corresponding JSF code will be.

My workings so far;

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{School.listschoolName}">
<f:selectItems value="#{School.listschoolName}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Java Class

```
//And also i got the corresponding getters and setters for these
private List<School> listschool; 

public void listschoolName(){
    setListschool(hml.findAllSchool());
}
```

The `findAllSchool()` method actually returns a `List<School>` object.

I need to display these School Names on a List Box (dropdown / selectOneMenu ). How can i do this ?

- I am using Netbeans 6.9.1 and Galssfish 3

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `var`, `itemLabel` and `itemValue` attributes :

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedSchool}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{School.listschoolName}" var="_school" itemValue="#{_school.id}" itemLabel="#{_school.name}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

According you have a getId() and getName() in the School class, and a getSelectedSchool() and setSelectedSchool(School s) in your managed bean.

Comment: The item value becomes the selected value. You've set the item value to be School ID. However the setter expects a School. So your answer is not exactly going to work :) See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-prepopulate-a-hselectonemenu-from-a-db

Comment: Yes, I've forgot the Convertor. Thank