# Save SelectItem[] to List<Hotel> object

Tags: java, jsf

I have a `List <Hotel>` object and I need to save it to a `SelectItem[]` object. How do I code this?

```
public List <Hotel> hotel;
public SelectItem[] food;
// followed by getters and setters
```

I need to save the `hotel` object to a `food` object. How do I code this in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just construct [`SelectItem`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html) objects with the desired value and label using its constructor. For example, with the hotel `id` as value and hotel `name` as label.

```
food = new SelectItem[hotels.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < hotels.size(); i++) {
    Hotel hotel = hotels.get(i);
    food[i] = new SelectItem(hotel.getId(), hotel.getName());
}
```

By the way, a `List<SelectItem>` is also supported by `<f:selectItems>`. That's easier to create.

```
food = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

for (Hotel hotel : hotels) {
    food.add(new SelectItem(hotel.getId(), hotel.getName()));
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, based on your question history, you're using JSF 2.0. You can just use `List<Hotel>` straight in the `<f:selectItems>` without the need for ugly `SelectItem` wrapper model. See also your previous question: [How to populate options of h:selectOneMenu from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-prepopulate-a-hselectonemenu-from-a-db)

Comment: I was trying [http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf ] the example and it gives an error when i try to add `List <Hotel>` so i thought to use `SelectItem[]` instead.