# How to preselect an option of h:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, initialization, selectonemenu

Is it possible to preselect one of the options from the select menu?

I have this UI Component:

```html
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{authenticateController.country}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{constants.countrySelectMenu}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The values of `#{constants.countrySelectMenu}` are a list of country ID - country name pairs.
Is there a way to render the list with a preselected value or at least is there a work-around to get this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just preset the property behind `<h:selectOneMenu value>` with the desired value. You can do it in for example the bean's (post)constructor, action(listener) method, etc.

In your specific example, thus e.g.

```
public class AuthenticateController {

    private String country;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        country = "NL";
    }

    // ...
}
```

It works exactly the same way for all other [`UIInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) components like `<h:inputText>` and so on. The input component's value itself simply represents the (pre)selected/checked/filled value.

#### See also:

- [How to populate options of h:selectOneMenu from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-prepopulate-hselectonemenu-with-entities-from-database)