# displaying values from database on the basis of dropdown menu selction

Tags: database, jsf, drop-down-menu

hi i am creating a JSF application . In fact I made a dropdown list and want to display the results according to the value selected from the dropdown. if somebody can help.... thanks

here is my drop down

```
<h:form>
                <h:commandButton action="sample?faces-redirect=true" value="submit">
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="sampleSearch" value="#{cBean.id}">
                    <f:selectItem id="id" itemLable="idText" itemValue="By Text" />
                    <f:selectItem id="idnumeric" itemLable="idNumeric" itemValue="Number" />
                    <f:selectItem id="product" itemLable="Product" itemValue="Main Product" />
                    <f:selectItem id="lonumber" itemLable="loNumber" itemValue="LoNumber" />
                    <f:selectItem id="formula" itemLable="formula" itemValue="By Formula" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </h:commandButton>

            </h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're not allowed to nest `<h:selectOneMenu>` component(s) within `<h:commandButton>`!
Here's a proper structure of your `<h:form>`

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton action="sample?faces-redirect=true" value="submit" />
        <h:selectOneMenu id="sampleSearch" value="#{cBean.id}">
            <f:selectItem id="id" itemLable="idText" itemValue="By Text" />
            <f:selectItem id="idnumeric" itemLable="idNumeric" itemValue="Number" />
            <f:selectItem id="product" itemLable="Product" itemValue="Main Product" />
            <f:selectItem id="lonumber" itemLable="loNumber" itemValue="LoNumber" />
            <f:selectItem id="formula" itemLable="formula" itemValue="By Formula" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

Then, in order to get the dropdown list options from the database, you can consider using the `<f:selectItems>` component (and get rid of those `<f:selectItem>`s) and pass a `List<T>` from the managed bean to the components `value` property.

The `selectOneMenu` would then look like this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{cBean.id}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{cBean.values}" 
                   var="item"
                   itemLabel="#{item.label}"
                   itemValue="#{item.value}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

As for the managed-bean, it's now supposed to provide a `public List<T> getValues()` method, which will return a list with the objects that will populate the dropdown.

When `T` is a complex Java object, such as `Item` which has a String property of `label` and `value`, then you could use the `var` attribute to get hold of the iteration variable which you in turn can use in `itemValue` and/or `itemLabel` attribtues (if you omit the `itemLabel`, then the label becomes the same as the value).

Let's say:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class CBean {
    public List<Item> getValues() {
        List<Item> result = new ArrayList<Item>();
        //..call-back to web-service, db, etc. and populate the result variable.
        return result;
    }
}
```

The `Item` class would look like this:

```
public class Item {
   private String label;
   private String value;

   //getters, setters.
}
```

You can read more here:

- [How to prepopulate a  from a DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6850681/1003142)

Comment: You forgot to mention that in case he uses a complex type like `Item` in your case, he also has to write a custom `ItemConverter`.

Comment: `Item` has two `String` properties (which are used as item and label), so there's no need of `ItemConverter`. In the cases in which the itemValue property holds the whole variable (like `itemValue="#{item}`) then a `Converter` is needed, because the `Item` object has to be represented as a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to read a book about JSF or at least some more tutorials about it. Your code makes not much sense. You nest a `selectOneMenu` inside of a `commandButton`. And if you want to display some values from your database, you should also call a method in your managed bean to do the query and retrieve the results.

That's how you should do it instead:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="sampleSearch" value="#{cBean.id}">
        <f:selectItem id="id" itemLable="idText" itemValue="By Text" />
        <f:selectItem id="idnumeric" itemLable="idNumeric" itemValue="Number" />
        <f:selectItem id="product" itemLable="Product" itemValue="Main Product" />
        <f:selectItem id="lonumber" itemLable="loNumber" itemValue="LoNumber" />
        <f:selectItem id="formula" itemLable="formula" itemValue="By Formula" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:commandButton action="#{cBean.search}" value="submit" />
</h:form>
```

And your bean would look like this:

```
public class CBean {
    private String id; // getter+setter

    public String search() {
        // perform your query based on the id value

        return "sample?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```