# Populate primefaces tag with database fields

Tags: jsf, label, selectonemenu

I would like to populate a `<p:selectOneMenu>` with `String` values from the database. So far, this is what I got (sorry about the Portugueese code):

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{onibusMB.nomeTransportadora}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{onibusMB.transportadoras}" var="transportadora" itemValue="#{transportadora}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Where my bean is:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class OnibusMB implements Serializable {

    private List<Transportadora> transportadoras;
    private String nomeTransportadora;
    /*getter, setter, etc

}
```

And my entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSPORTADORA")
public class Transportadora implements AbstractEntity {

    private String nome;

}
```

I tried a few changes in that, but none has worked. The label shows always:

```
com.ezpass.model.Transportadora@2ce4a0c2
```

How can I show the `nome` property of `Transportdora` in label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set the `itemLabel` attribute.

```
<f:selectItems ... itemLabel="#{transportadora.nome}" />
```

The `itemValue` only sets the actual item value, not the item label. The item value is what's been submitted from client to server. The item label is what's been shown to the world. If the item label is absent, then by default the item value is shown. But as it's a complex entity and you didn't specify any converter, then it defaults to `toString()` result of `Transportadora` class.

#### See also:

- [How to populate options of h:selectOneMenu from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-prepopulate-a-hselectonemenu-from-a-db)
- [Our `selectOneMenu` wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you perhaps also want to set `itemValue` to the same as in

```
<f:selectItems ... itemValue="#{transportadora.nome}" />
```

because your property is a `String`, not a `Transportdora`. You (read: JSF) can't set a `Transportdora` object in a `String` property. Otherwise, you need to change it to `#{onibusMB.transportadora}` and provide a converter.

Comment: It worked fine just by setting the itemLabel atribute. Even with a ""nome" cannot be resolved" warning in it.

Comment: You're welcome. That warning is because the average IDE pretends to be smarter than it actually is as to validating EL expressions. EL is so complex, no one IDE is completely flawless in this. Eclipse not, Netbeans not and even IntelliJ not.

Comment: Hum...i see. I will pay atention to that. Usually with theese warningns i tend to believe something is wrong with the code. I use Eclipse. Thanks a lot, man.

Comment: Indeed. Just follow the documentation and just run the code outright regardless of the EL warnings. If it works, then you may assume that it's valid. If necessary, disable EL validation altogether in IDE preferences.