# How to use SelectManyCheckbox with two ArrayList? - Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectmanycheckbox

I'm trying to implement a [`<p:selectManyCheckbox>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectManyCheckbox.jsf) but I'm having no success.

**Now I have the following architecture:**

```
Course - have many Disciplines
Discipline - belongs to none, one or many Courses.
```

In `Course` class I have two `ArrayList<Discipline>`:

```
public class CourseMBean{

    (...)
    // Stores all disciplines
    private static ArrayList<Discipline> allDisciplines;

    // Stores only the disciplines that's already associated with this course.
    private static ArrayList<Discipline> courseDisciplines;

    (get and set for the arraylists)
    (...)
}
```

All data comes from a MYSQL DB, but that isn't the question. Now I want create a new Course, so I don't have anything in courseDisciplines.

I want show allDisciplines in checkboxes, and want that when user select one checkbox, the object Discipline of this checkbox be added in courseDisciplines - and when unselect one checkbox, remove the discipline from the courseDsiciplines.

**My JSF 2.0 code is following:**

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="disciplines" value="#{courseMBean.allDisciplines}" layout="grid" columns="2">                                          
     <f:selectItems value="#{courseMBean.courseDisciplines}" />
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

This actually shows all disciplines without any selected checkboxes, what's right. But when I select some checkboxes and submit the form I try to print the elements inside courseDisciplines, and this don't show anything in console.

**What I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: Is selectManyCheckbox enclosed in a form? Whats the scope of CourseMBean?

Comment: yes, he's inside a form and the scope is @SessionScoped.Is something wrong, this should work as I desired?

Comment: I have a hard time in understanding your problem. Why are you trying to print the available items instead of the selected items and why are the available items apparently empty but yet you can apparently select them in the UI?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *when I select some checkboxes and submit the form I try to print the elements inside courseDisciplines*

As the `courseDisciplines` actually represents the *available* items not the *selected* items, it seems that you misunderstood some basic concepts around the `UISelectMany` and `UISelectItem(s)` components.

The `<f:selectItem(s)>` (from the `UISelectItem(s)` family) represent the **available** items. It are exactly those items which are shown in the UI and which the enduser has to choose from.

The `value` attribute of `<p:selectManyCheckbox>` (from the `UISelectMany` family, like `<h:selectManyCheckbox>` and `<h:selectManyMenu>`) represent the **(pre)selected** items. If this is null or empty during first display of the form, then nothing is preselected. Or if this contains some preselected items, then only those available items which are `equal()` will be preselected.

When the enduser has changed the selection in the UI and submits the form, then all selected items will end up in the `value` attribute of `UISelectMany` component. The `UISelectItem(s)` remains unchanged.

Here's a basic kickoff example:

```html
<p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.selectedItems}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
<p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
<p:messages autoUpdate="true" />
```

```java
private List<String> selectedItems; // +getter +setter
private List<String> availableItems; // +getter (no setter necessary!)

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    availableItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    availableItems.add("one");
    availableItems.add("two");
    availableItems.add("three");
}

public void submit() {
    System.out.println("Selected items: " + selectedItems);
}
```

*(all other `<p:selectManyXxx>` and `<h:selectManyXxx>` components work exactly the same)*

When a complex Javabean object like `Discipline` comes into the picture, then you need to make sure that there's a `Converter` for that so that JSF can properly convert between it and `String` for usage in generated HTML output and as HTTP request parameter (HTML and HTTP namely can't pass around nor hold Java objects, but only character sequences which are in Java represented by `String`).

This is perhaps your root problem. You said that nothing is printed to the console on submit. But it could be as good the case that the whole `submit()` method is actually never being invoked. You're not explicit enough on this. If the whole action method is indeed never invoked (i.e. a debug breakpoint doesn't hit there, or another `System.out.println()` printing a static string is never shown in console), then you've actually most likely a conversion error. If you have used `<h|p:message(s)>` the right way, or have paid attention to server log about queued but undisplayed faces messages, then you should have noticed it.

In that case, you need to implement a `Converter` which converts between `Discipline` and `String`.

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Discipline.class)
public class DisciplineConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        // Write code here to convert from String to Discipline.
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) {
        // Write code here to convert from Discipline to String.
    }

}
```

More than often the DB ID is being used as `String` representation. See also the section "Complex object as selected item" of this answer on a related question: [How to populate options of h:selectOneMenu from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-prepopulate-a-hselectonemenu-from-a-db/6850681#6850681)

Comment: Thanks again Balusc! Just a little question: In the converter, can I get the Discipline "id" value instead Discipline "name"? I say this because handle strings isn't too secure and fast as ints (id), it's more secure get a value from DB with ID instead of "name", right?

Comment: I used Omnifaces, from your another answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-prepopulate-a-hselectonemenu-from-a-db/6850681#6850681 Thanks again!