# h:selecteOneMenu values

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

I have the following files in my application but I can't get the values from the selectOneMenu on file elementoUpdateDialog.xhtml to update the dataTable on gerirElementos.xhtml and sql table.

Where is my error?

**elementoUpdateDialog.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:body>
<p:dialog widgetVar="elementoUpdateDialogWidget"
    id="elementoUpdateDialogId" height="300" width="500" modal="true"
    closable="true" draggable="false" resizable="false">
    <h:form id="elementoUpdateDialogForm" prependId="false">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="elementoID" />
            <h:inputText value="#{elementoMB.elemento.elementoId}"
                required="true" label="elementoID" />

            <h:outputText value="Posto" />
            <h:outputText value="#{elementoMB.elemento.posto.postoId}"         />               
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{postoMB.posto.postoId}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{postoMB.allPostos}" var     ="posto"
                itemLabel="#{postoMB.posto.posto}" itemValue="#    {elementoMB.elemento.posto.postoId}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <br />
            <h:outputText value="Classe" /> 
            <h:outputText value="#{elementoMB.elemento.classe.classeId}" />     
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#    {elementoMB.elemento.classe.classeId}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{classeMB.allClasses}"/>
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#    {elementoMB.elemento.classe.classeId}" itemLabel="#{elementoMB.elemento.classe.classeId}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <br/>
            <h:outputText value="Nome" />
            <h:inputText value="#{elementoMB.elemento.nome}"     required="true"
                label="Nome" />
            <h:outputText value="NII" />
            <h:inputText value="#{elementoMB.elemento.NII}"     required="true"
                label="NII" />

            <p:commandButton value="Gravar" icon="ui-icon-plus"
                action="#{elementoMB.updateElemento()}"
                update=":messageGrowl     :elementosForm:elementosTable"
                oncomplete="closeDialogIfSucess(xhr, status, args,      elementoUpdateDialogWidget, 'elementoUpdateDialogId')" />
            <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" icon="ui-icon-cancel"
                actionListener="#{elementoMB.resetElemento()}"
                onclick="elementoUpdateDialogWidget.hide();"     type="button" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**gerirElementos.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>


</h:head>
<h:body>
<ui:composition template="/pages/protected/templates/master.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="divMain">
        <p:menubar>
            <p:submenu label="Elementos" icon="ui-icon-contact">
                <p:menuitem value="Listar"
                    url="/pages/protected/defaultUser/gerirElementos.xhtml" />
            </p:submenu>

            <p:submenu label="Classes" icon="ui-icon-contact">
                <p:menuitem value="Listar"
                    url="/pages/protected/admin/gerirClasses.xhtml" />
            </p:submenu>

            <p:submenu label="Postos" icon="ui-icon-contact">
                <p:menuitem value="Listar"
                    url="/pages/protected/admin/gerirPostos.xhtml" />
            </p:submenu>

            <p:submenu label="RegistoSarPerm" icon="ui-icon-contact">
                <p:menuitem value="Listar"
                    url="/pages/protected/defaultUser/gerirRegistoSarPerm.xhtml" />
            </p:submenu>


        </p:menubar>

        <h:form id="elementosForm">

            <p:dataTable id="elementosTable" var="elemento"
                value="#{elementoMB.allElementos}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                selepaginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="1,5,10">

                <f:facet name="header">  
        Lista de Elementos  
    </f:facet>

                <p:column headerText="NII" sortBy="nii" id="nii">  
        #{elemento.NII}  
    </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Posto" sortBy="posto" id="posto">  
        #{elemento.posto.posto}  
    </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Classe" sortBy="classe" id="classe">  
        #{elemento.classe.classe}  
    </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Nome" sortBy="nome" id="nome">  
        #{elemento.nome}  
    </p:column>
                <p:column>

                    <p:spacer width="10px" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Editar" icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                        update=":elementoUpdateDialogForm"
                        onclick="elementoUpdateDialogWidget.show();">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{elementoMB.elemento}"
                            value="#{elemento}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:spacer width="10px" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Eliminar" icon="ui-icon-trash"
                        update=":elementoDeleteDialogForm"
                        onclick="elementoDeleteDialogWidget.show();">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{elementoMB.elemento}"
                            value="#{elemento}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:spacer width="10px" />

                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
            <p:commandButton value="Novo Elemento" icon="ui-icon-plus"
                actionListener="#{elementoMB.resetElemento()}"
                onclick="elementoCreateDialogWidget.show();" />
        </h:form>
        <ui:include
            src="/pages/protected/defaultUser/dialogs/elementoCreateDialog.xhtml" />
        <ui:include
            src="/pages/protected/defaultUser/dialogs/elementoUpdateDialog.xhtml" />
        <ui:include
                src="/pages/protected/defaultUser/dialogs/elementoDeleteDialog.xhtml" />
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**Elemento.java**

```
package com.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Elemento")

public class Elemento implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="elementoId")
private int elementoId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "classeId")
private Classe classe;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="postoID")
private Posto posto;


@Column(name="NII")
private String NII;

@Column(name="nome")
private String nome;

public Elemento(){

}

public Elemento(String NII, String nome){
    this.NII = NII;
    this.nome = nome;
}

//Getters and Setters
public int getElementoId() {
    return elementoId;
}

public void setElementoId(int elementoId) {
    this.elementoId = elementoId;
}




public String getNII() {
    return NII;
}

public void setNII(String nII) {
    NII = nII;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}



public Classe getClasse() {
    return classe;
}

public void setClasse(Classe classe) {
    this.classe = classe;
}

public Posto getPosto() {
    return posto;
}

public void setPosto(Posto posto) {
    this.posto = posto;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return elementoId;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Elemento) {
        Elemento elemento = (Elemento) obj;
        return elemento.getElementoId() == elementoId;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

**ElementoMB.java**

```
package com.mb;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import com.facade.ElementoFacade;
import com.model.Classe;
import com.model.Elemento;
import com.model.Posto;

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class ElementoMB extends AbstractMB implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



private Posto posto;
private Classe classe;
private Elemento elemento;


private List<Elemento> elementos;

private ElementoFacade elementoFacade;

public void createElemento() {
    try {
        getElementoFacade().createElemento(elemento);;
        closeDialog();
        displayInfoMessageToUser("Created With Sucess");
        loadElementos();
        resetElemento();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        keepDialogOpen();
        displayErrorMessageToUser("Ops, we could not create. Try again later");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void updateElemento() {
    try {
        getElementoFacade().updateElemento(elemento);
        closeDialog();
        displayInfoMessageToUser("Updated With Sucess");
        loadElementos();
        resetElemento();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        keepDialogOpen();
        displayErrorMessageToUser("Ops, we could not create. Try again later");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void deleteElemento() {
    try {
        getElementoFacade().deleteElemento(elemento);
        closeDialog();
        displayInfoMessageToUser("Deleted With Sucess");
        loadElementos();
        resetElemento();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        keepDialogOpen();
        displayErrorMessageToUser("Ops, we could not create. Try again later");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public List<Elemento> getAllElementos(){
    if (elementos == null){
        loadElementos();
    }
    return elementos;
}

public ElementoFacade getElementoFacade() {
    if (elementoFacade == null) {
        elementoFacade = new ElementoFacade();
    }

    return elementoFacade;
}

public Elemento getElemento() {
    if (elemento == null) {
        elemento = new Elemento();
    }

    return elemento;
}

public void setElemento(Elemento elemento) {
    this.elemento = elemento;
}



private void loadElementos() {
    elementos = getElementoFacade().listAll();
}



public void resetElemento() {
    elemento = new Elemento();
}



public Posto getPosto() {
    if (posto == null){
        posto = new Posto();
    }
    return posto;
}

public void setPosto(Posto posto) {
    this.posto = posto;
}

public Classe getClasse() {
    if (classe == null) {
        classe = new Classe();
    }

    return classe;
}

public void setClasse(Classe classe) {
    this.classe = classe;
}

public void resetClasse() {
    classe = new Classe();
}


}
```

**ElementoFacade.java**

```
package com.facade;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import com.dao.ElementoDAO;
import com.model.Elemento;

public class ElementoFacade implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private ElementoDAO elementoDAO = new ElementoDAO();
public void createElemento(Elemento elemento) {
    elementoDAO.beginTransaction();
    elementoDAO.save(elemento);
    elementoDAO.commitAndCloseTransaction();
}

public void updateElemento(Elemento elemento) {
    elementoDAO.beginTransaction();
    Elemento persistedElemento = elementoDAO.find(elemento.getElementoId());
    persistedElemento.setNome(elemento.getNome());
    persistedElemento.setNII(elemento.getNII());
    elementoDAO.commitAndCloseTransaction();
}

public void deleteElemento(Elemento elemento){
    elementoDAO.beginTransaction();
    Elemento persistedElementoWithIdOnly = elementoDAO.findReferenceOnly(elemento.getElementoId());
    elementoDAO.delete(persistedElementoWithIdOnly);
    elementoDAO.commitAndCloseTransaction();

}

public Elemento findElemento(int elementoId) {
    elementoDAO.beginTransaction();
    Elemento elemento = elementoDAO.find(elementoId);
    elementoDAO.closeTransaction();
    return elemento;
}

public List<Elemento> listAll() {
    elementoDAO.beginTransaction();
    List<Elemento> result = elementoDAO.findAll();
    elementoDAO.closeTransaction();
    return result;
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here,

```
<f:selectItems value="#{postoMB.allPostos}" var="posto"
    itemLabel="#{postoMB.posto.posto}" itemValue="#{elementoMB.elemento.posto.postoId}"/>
```

Your `itemLabel` and `itemValue` attributes, representing the current option label and value, are wrong. They're for some unclear reason referencing a backing bean property instead of the currently iterated option object as definied in `var="posto"`.

Fix it accordingly:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{postoMB.allPostos}" var="posto"
    itemLabel="#{posto.postoId}" itemValue="#{posto}"/>
```

This should display the items correctly.

And here,

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{postoMB.posto.postoId}">
```

the selected item is wrong. This would only cause problems during submitting and during displaying a preselected item. You should refer the very same type as `itemValue` itself, not some ID (otherwise you're changing only the `id` of an entity instead of the entity itself, resulting in major potential trouble as those are references):

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{postoMB.posto}">
```

Supply if necessary a converter in case you don't have a `@FacesConverter(forClass=Posto.class)`.

Apply the same lesson learnt on the other `<h:selectOneMenu>` you've there.

#### See also:

- [Our `<h:selectOneMenu>` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)
- [How to populate options of h:selectOneMenu from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-prepopulate-a-hselectonemenu-from-a-db/6850681#6850681)