# JSF custom converter fails on unicode string

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, unicode, converters, glassfish-4

Tweaked the converter from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6850681/281545)

```
// @FacesConverter(forClass = Crew.class) // no injection
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public static class CrewConverter implements Converter {

    @EJB
    private CrewService cs;

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) {
        return (value instanceof Crew) ? ((Crew) value).getName() : null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println("value : " + value);
        List<Crew> allCrew = cs.allCrew();
        for (Crew crew : allCrew) {
            if (crew.getName().equals(value)) {
                System.out.println("value found: " + value);
                return crew;
            }
        }
        throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(String.format(
            "Cannot convert %s to Crew", value)));
    }
}
```

On one of the items the converter fails with:

> Cannot convert ÎÎ±Î½Î¬ÏÎ·Ï ÎÎ­Î³Î³Î¿Ï to Crew

For the rest conversion passes (<del>but not validation which is another matter</del> I had to define `equals()` in Crew!)

The value is displayed correctly - should I tweak the converter or the problem may lie deeper (in the server config) ?

I am on glassfish 4

EDIT - the form:

```
<h:form id="movie_crew_form"
    rendered="#{movieController.movie  != null}" >
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:selectOneListbox id="crewMember" redisplay="true" size="8"
        value="#{movieController.crewMember}"
        converter="#{movieController$CrewConverter}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{movieController.allCrew}" var="entry"
            itemValue="#{entry}" itemLabel="#{entry.name}" />
        <f:ajax event="blur" render="crewMemberMessage" />
    </h:selectOneListbox>
    <h:message id="crewMemberMessage" for="crewMember" />
</h:panelGrid>
<h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{movieController.addCrewMember}" />
</h:form>
```

**EDIT2**: the message appears when I hit the "Add" button - when I alt-tab out of the form (so onBlur is triggered) the conversion works ! Sample output (on eclipse console)

On alt tab:

```
INFO: value : ??????? ??????
FINE: SELECT IDCREW, NAME FROM CREW
INFO: value found: ??????? ??????
FINE: SELECT IDCREW, NAME FROM CREW
FINE: SELECT IDCREW, NAME FROM CREW
```

On "Add":

```
INFO: value : ??????? ??????
FINE: SELECT IDCREW, NAME FROM CREW
INFO: value found: ??????? ??????
FINE: SELECT IDCREW, NAME FROM CREW
FINE: SELECT IDCREW, NAME FROM CREW
INFO: value : Î?Î±Î½Î¬Ï?Î·Ï? Î?Î­Î³Î³Î¿Ï?
FINE: SELECT IDCREW, NAME FROM CREW
FINE: SELECT IDCREW, NAME FROM CREW
```

The funny thing is that when this mojibake is displayed it actually lets me press the "Add" button a second time and the method `addCrewMember()` *is called* resulting in a constraint violation (which I expect).

Comment: Your question is confusing. The converter seems to work fine. What's the current state of the problem? That Eclipse fails to properly print characters outside CP1252 / ISO-8859-1 range to the stdout?

Comment: @BalusC: No no - when I press "Add" I see the message on the page `Cannot convert ÎÎ±Î½Î¬ÏÎ·Ï ÎÎ­Î³Î³Î¿Ï to Crew`. I just posted the printouts in eclipse - when I have selected the name with unicode chars and hit "Add" first time it runs it says `value : ??????? ??????` - which is alright (I know I have to set the console in UTF-8 in eclipse), does the same on alt tab out of the browser window - and second time it shows  `value : Î?Î±Î½Î¬Ï?Î·Ï? Î?Î­Î³Î³Î¿Ï?` - here it fails to convert.

Comment: @BalusC: why it runs two time and who feeds it the (already garbled) input the second time is the issue

Comment: But the symptom of `?`s being printed suggests that Eclipse isn't at all instructed to use UTF-8 in stdout.

Comment: @BalusC: yes - and it turns out it's not simple either cause there is no run configuration to set. But eclipse is not the problem - the ??? is unicode read correctly and displayed badly but why the `Î?Î±Î½Î¬Ï?Î·Ï? Î?Î­Î³Î³Î¿Ï?` ? - I solved it (see my answer), but I don't understand why - it is a lifecycle something I miss. I'd accept an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the button to this:

```
<h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{movieController.addCrewMember}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
</h:commandButton>
```

solved it.