# Select Drop Down list automatically in JSF

Tags: java, sql, jsf, javabeans

I tried to select automatically the drop down list options from the values in DB.

```
        <td class="labelInfo">Processing</td>
        <td class="cellInfo" width="35%"><h:selectOneMenu value="#{visaAction.visaBean.processing}">
      <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="---Select---" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Normal" itemLabel="Normal" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Urgent" itemLabel="Urgent" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    </td>


<td class="labelInfo"><SPAN class="star">Group Membership(if Any)</SPAN></td>
                            <td class="cellInfo" width="35%"><h:selectOneMenu value="#{visaAction.visaBean.groupMembership}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="---Select---" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Main/Only" itemLabel="Main/Only" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Son" itemLabel="Son" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Daughter" itemLabel="Daughter" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Wife" itemLabel="Wife" />
                                </h:selectOneMenu></td>
```

How to retrieve values from DB and set those values to JSF page

Comment: Help me out ..how to set values to the list while the page opening itself

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-prepopulate-a-hselectonemenu-from-a-db/