# selectOneMenu of PrimeFaces breaks when calling from ajax

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Below is screenshot of selectOneMenu break

[image]

Below is my code :

```
<h:form>
   <h:commandLink  value="Edit"> 
    <p:ajax event="action" update=":editPanel" listener="#{myBean.open(productItem,'edit')}"/>
   </h:commandLink> 
</h:form>

<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="editPanel">
   <h:form>
      <p:selectOneMenu label="hello" value="hello">
        <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{mybean.labelvalueList}" itemValue="#{mybean.valueList}"/>
      </p:selectOneMenu>
   </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

I am facing problem in display selectonemenu of PrimeFaces when event fire using ajax, as per my observation it will break combobox functionality when ajax call ,one more thing data from back end coming properly there is problem with display only.

Anybody can help me to fix this problem ?
I am using PrimeFaces 5

Comment: Why don't use a `<p:commandLink>` instead (PrimeFaces one) while using PrimeFaces in which `ajax` is set to true by default?

Comment: You need to add a screenshot.

Comment: It's not working, same problem arise.

Comment: You have embedded a `<p:selectOneMenu>` inside another different `<h:form>`. Why? This appears to be absolutely superfluous.

Comment: In addition to that `<p:selectOneMenu>` has serious problems. You need to use the `var` and `value` attributes along with `<f:selectItems>` which in turn requires an appropriate converter, if the list of items in the `<p:selectOneMenu>` contains composite/complex objects and the `value` attribute of `<p:selectOneMenu>` is supposed to be set/bound to an appropriate bean property with an appropriate data type.

Comment: <p:selectOneMenu> update another <p:selectOneMenu> based on selection ,so its inside <h:form>

Comment: <f:selectItems> contains only list of String

Comment: If it contains only a list of strings then, it should go just like `<f:selectItems value="#{bean.list}" />`. Those `itemLabel` and `itemValue` attributes of `<f:selectItems>` refer to something which implicitly implies that you want a list of items in the `<p:selectOneMenu>` having different values and labels. If it is the case then use `var` and `value` appropriately in the given `<f:selectItems>` and map the `<p:selectOneMenu>` to an appropriate bean property using its `value` attribute as stated earlier.

Comment: The whole story is appropriately mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6850681/1391249).

Comment: I also tried <f:selectItems value="#{bean.list}" but it's not working. May be I do some minor mistake.