# How do UISelectOne and UISelectMany components preselect defaults in f:selectItems

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu, selectmanymenu

I know how to preselect `<p:selectOneMenu>`, in selected `value` should be one of the objects from `<f:selectItems>`, but how does this component work under the hood and can I change this behavior?

In my case I've a duplicate object, actually this is two objects with the same values but created twice and selected object in `<p:selectOneMenu>` differs from object from `<f:selectItems>` and it doens't recognize it.
Most likely I will change my design so, it will point to same object but in case I can't do it due to legacy code or etc, how can I change the behavior of `<p:selectOneMenu>` that it will compare objects by `id` for example?

I'd thought that `converter` responsible for it, but when it rendered it doesn't enter on `getAsObject` method only `getAsString`, so I guess that there's something different, but what?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It uses [`Object#equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) for that. You can change (fix) this behavior by implementing it accordingly on your entity.

```
private Long id;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return (other != null && getClass() == other.getClass() && id != null)
        ? id.equals(getClass().cast(other).id)
        : (other == this);
}
```

Don't forget the [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) to satisfy the [equals-hashCode contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--).

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (id != null) 
        ? (getClass().hashCode() + id.hashCode())
        : super.hashCode();
}
```

If you can't change the existing entity for some unclear reason, wrap it in your own DTO.

The converter only converts between the entity and its unique `String` representation for usage in HTML output and HTTP request parameters and has therefore no influence on preselection. It has only influence on potential [Validation Error: Value is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069379/validation-error-value-is-not-valid/) trouble.

#### See also:

- [How to populate options of h:selectOneMenu from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-prepopulate-a-hselectonemenu-with-complex-objects-entities-from-a-db)