# Primefaces SelectManyMenu of list of objects, set pre-selected values from another list

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, selectmanymenu

I have an `ArrayList` of a custom object (`ArrayList<Cell> allCells`)  and a `sublist` of allList (`ArrayList<Cell> checkedCells`) . What I would like to do is display the **allCells** arraylist in a `p:selectManyMenu` and show the objects of my sublist **checkedCells** as `checked` in the menu.

I know that the above question is supposed to have already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34547061/primefaces-selectmanymenu-loading-default-values) but I think that the answer is of low quality and unclear for such a basic question, and additionally the OP does not make use of the `converter` which I need to use.

**Cell class**

```
public class Cell{
  private String value;
  // rest member variables getters setters default constructor ommitted
}
```

**CellConverter class**

```
@FacesConverter(forClass= Cell.class,  value = "cellConverter")
public class CellConverter implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    else{
        CellBean cellBean = (CellBean) context.getViewRoot().getViewMap().get("cellBean");
        for(Cell cell  : cellBean.getAllCells()){
            String s = cell.getValue();
            if(s.equals(value)){
                return cell;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
        return "";
    }
    if (!(value instanceof Cell)) {
        throw new ConverterException("sth went wrong");
    }
    Cell cell = (Cell) value;
    return cell.getValue();
}
```

**selectManyMenu code**

```
<p:selectManyMenu converter="cellConverter" value="#{cellBean.checkedCells}"
                  var="cell" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" showCheckbox="true">
   <f:selectItems value="#{cellBean.allCells}"
    var="entity" itemLabel="#{entity.value}" itemValue="#{entity}" />
   <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{cell.value}" />
   </p:column>
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

Unfortunately, even though the **list is shown properly in the selectmanymenu, the elements belonging to the `checkedCells` list are not checked**

Assuming the `checkedCells` list includes cells with values `cell2 and cell4`

I would like the list to be shown like this

[image]

but the list is shown like this (even though i debugged the `checkedCells variable and is actually includes this values)

[image]

**Primefaces version: 7.0**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work if not using the `p:column`? Does it work with other similar components (select chekbox)? Does it work with a plain jsf `h:selectManyMenu`?  Or the checkbox ones?

Comment: If not, you can 'generalize' your search...

Comment: No they do not :/ . I also tried with `selectManyCheckbox` but still no luck, any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: @Kukeltje bingo! Indeed what I needed was a custom implementation of the `equals` method in the `Cell` object. Thank you !