# Select One Menu from Database in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I want to make a selectonemenu form that display data from 1 table 
`ahmdsmun_msttypeclr` that consist of 3 columns:
- `VTYPECODE` (PK) (string)
- `VCLRCODE` (string)
- `VCLRDESC` (string)

I want to make VCLRDESC in my selectonemenu form.

I have read this link [How to populate options of h:selectOneMenu from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-prepopulate-hselectonemenu-with-entities-from-database) that answered by BalusC so detail.
But I am confused which one I should use for my problem because I don't get the use of converter and the differences to implement between string and Object

Thank you in advance

Comment: @BalusC, so with my question here, did I need this converter?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want a selectonemenu that displays VCLRDESC and returns VTYPECODE when your user choose an option. So I think you just should follow the "Complex objects as available items" section from the link you mentioned:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.entities}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.neededValue}" var="entity" itemValue="#{entity.VTYPECODE}" itemLabel="#{entity.VCLRDESC}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. 
may you you tell me what "entities" mean? and the differences between itemValue and itemLabel?
and my problem, I need to display VCLRDESC and save the selected VCLRDESC to another table in database.