# selectItems itemValue not recognized, returns hash code instead

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm a little stuck with a `selectOneMenu`.
I have a DB table `foo` with a Bean and DAO as well as a POJO. I have already established a working CRUD page thanks to [BalusC's great tutorial](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html#ReallySimpleCRUDNowWithoutDataModel).

`Foo` has the columns `id`, `text`, and `a1` to `a5` as further values.

The menu only displays a list of hash codes, like "com.example.beans.foo@3a3526c3", no matter what I put as `itemValue`. I can put in `blabla` as well, the result is the same.

Here's the JSF.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<f:view><h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value=#{fooBean.id}> 
      <f:selectItems value="#{fooBean.list}" var="foo" itemValue="#{foo.id}" itemLabel="#{foo.text}" /> 
    </h:selectOneMenu> 
  </h:column> 
</h:form>
</f:view>
</html>
```

And here's `foo`:

```
@ManagedBean (name = "foo")
@ViewScoped
public class Foo implements Serializable {
    private String text;
    private String id;
//getters and setters
}
```

and `fooBean`:

```
@ManagedBean (name="fooBean")
@ViewScoped
public class FooBean implements Serializable {
    private List<Foo> list;
    private Foo foo = new Foo();
    private boolean edited;
    private String id;
    private String text;
    @EJB
    private FooDAO fooDAO;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        list = fooDAO.getAll();
    }

    public void add() {
        String id = fooDAO.insert(foo);
        foo.setId(id);
        list.add(foo);
        foo = new Foo();
    }

    public void edit(Foo Foo) {
        this.foo = Foo;
        edited = true;
    }

    public void save() {
        fooDAO.update(foo);
        foo = new Foo();
        edited = false;
    }

    public void delete(Foo Foo) {
        fooDAO.delete(Foo);
        list.remove(Foo);
    }

    public List<Foo> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public boolean isEdited() {
        return edited;
    }    
  public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}


}
```

Comment: With "JVM memory addresses" in the first dropdown with `<f:selectItems var>`, you actually mean the `toString()` result of the custom `Foo` class which look like `com.example.Foo@hashcode` by default? Exactly as you'd get when you do `System.out.println(foo)`? (hash code is no memory address btw). If so, then this suggests that you're actually running JSF 1.x not JSF 2.x. Which JSF version is logged during startup and which JSF version is your `faces-config.xml` declared to?

Comment: my `faces-config` is declared to version 2.2, and on startup my server log says Mojarra 2.2.1. I first accidentaly indeed used 1.2, but replaced it in the dependencies with Mojarra 2.2.1 and javax.faces-api 2.2 after that. And after reading the tuts, I thought that for `String` values I didn't have to manually override `toString()` in my objects

Comment: Post a MCVE with (un)expected behavior exactly described. "JVM memory addresses" is not an exact description. "com.example.Foo@12345678" is an exact description.

Comment: OK added the other modules to provide a MCVE as minimal as possible for the two issues and edited the question. If it's too much code, then I'll have to split up the question.

Comment: MCVE is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info The table and other dropdowns are irrelevant to the problem. You can just reduce this from the question to make it better focused.

Comment: ok I trimmed it down and will post the other problem as another question

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-prepopulate-hselectonemenu-with-entities-from-database

Comment: I modified it (and this question too) according to the answer in that question; still, I get the same result, and no error messages. I know I shouldn't consider this too much, but even my IDE gives me the right values on autocompletion (.name, .id), so I assume that it's constructed right. I just can't find the error, and it's pretty frustrating.

Comment: The display is done by `itemLabel`, not `itemValue`. Your `Foo` class should not have been a `@ManagedBean` at all, it would only conflict with `#{foo}` from `var="foo"`. The `FooBean` contains code irrelevant to the problem, try creating a real MCVE instead of editing inline and untesting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `Foo` was a `ManagedBean`. I removed the entry and voilà, it worked. Thanks @BalusC!