# JSF SelectOneMenu value cannot be user defined type?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm very new to JSF!

I'm using a PrimeFaces selectOneMenu and spent several hours reading questions trying to figure out why either (1) the ajax listener wasn't getting called or (2) why the selectedCategory wasn't updated. Now it works, but I had to change the type getting passed to my bean in `value="#{categoryList.selectedCategory}"` to a `String`. Before I was using a `Category` object. Why is that? `Category` **does** implement `java.io.Serializable` if that's important.

Here is my code:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="ddlCategories" value="#{categoryList.selectedCategory}"
                 style="width:125px">
    <p:ajax event="change" update="artistGrid" immediate="true"
               listener="#{UFOUser.showArtists()}" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="All Categories" itemValue="null" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{categoryList.categories}" var="category"
                 itemLabel="#{category.name} (#{category.abbreviation})"                   
                          itemValue="#{category.getID()}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: For custom classes used in `selectOneMenu ` you need converter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-populate-options-of-hselectonemenu-from-database

Comment: If you follow some tutorials, this will all be discussed in them...

Comment: @Geinmachi Aha! Great thank you!