# JSF Unable to trace Client Id missing component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am getting below error , while using JSF with tomcat.

```
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.saveDynamicActions Unable to save dynamic action with clientId j_id56 because the UIComponent cannot be found.
```

I know the issue comes due to component not having id.
But i have assigned id to every component other then   p:outputLabel  , p:panel  , p:panelGrid .
Can anyone help me out how to trace that which component is responsible for this issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That can happen if you manipulate the component tree programmatically instead of declaratively (e.g. `binding`, `findComponent()`, `remove()` and what not). Create and post a [mcve]. Then we can point out the mistake.

Comment: @BalusC, if I am going to manipulate the component tree programmatically when do I have to set a component to be transient ?

Answer (score 1):

f:selectItem was populating from DB, i solved this by adding

```
transient="true"
```

in every item/items.

Comment: You seem to have a major [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and this is most likely the solution you're actually looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6848970 In the meanwhile, carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/q/14911158 and clean up your codebase.