# How to add values to list using Java

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create a list and add values to it but getting nullpointer exception. Can you please assist.
Below is my Java code:

```
acctTypeCodes = new ArrayList();
cumBalIndicators.add(new SelectItem("Y", "Y"));
cumBalIndicators.add(new SelectItem("N", "N"));
```

Below is the error from log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jet.bean.GlAcctRefMBean.getCumBalIndicators(GlAcctRefMBean.java:185)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the variable cumBalIndicators is initialized?

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42638917/how-to-submit-null-value-in-pselectone-primefaces

Comment: If you have a new question, do not chameleonize an existing and already answered question. Instead, ask a new question. I rolled back your initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cumBalIndicators` is not initialized. If it is a class property its default value is `null`.
You need to initialize it as follow:

```
private List<SelectItem> cumBalIndicators = new ArrayList<>(); // or any other implementation of the List interface
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The error is resolved.  I have another question  I changed the list as below but when we chose select as the drop down value it doesnt save null to the database. Can you please let me know   public List<SelectItem> getCumBalIndicators()
   { 
   cumBalIndicators = new ArrayList<SelectItem>(); 
   cumBalIndicators.add(new SelectItem("", "Select"));
   cumBalIndicators.add(new SelectItem("Y", "Y"));
   cumBalIndicators.add(new SelectItem("N", "N"));
   return cumBalIndicators ;
   }

Comment: Below is my xhtml:  <f:facet name="input">
      <h:selectOneMenu value="#{glAcctRefRecord.cumIndicator}" label="Cumulative Balance Indicator">
       <f:selectItems value="#{glAcctRefMBean.cumBalIndicators}" />
      </h:selectOneMenu>
     </f:facet>

Comment: Hi @shilpa_M can you post the code in the question? Here in the comments is a mess to read

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I updated the description. I am using jsf selectone menu to display drop down values , when I chose select as the drop down value it should be updated to null but it shows Y/N whichever the user might have previously chosen as dropdown.

Comment: I'm not an expert on JSF, but usually List is not a good choice for fetching/updating values, as it has no key-value mapping (like Map)

Comment: I am able to update Y/N but only when I chose select it doesn't update it to null

Comment: On SelectItem have you implemented the toString() method?

Comment: nope. We need to implement this within a managed Bean? Any pseudo code or reference?

Comment: Try reading this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-populate-options-of-hselectonemenu-from-database

Comment: Thank you for the link. I am not reading the drop down list from the database instead creating it in the bean with Y/N/select values.