# SelectOneMenu with PrimeFaces or BootsFaces not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, bootsfaces

I would like to use `SelectOneMenu` with PrimeFaces or BootsFaces and fill it with JPA. My problem is: when I update the data, `SelectOneMenu` does not have the correct item selected.

But if I use normal JSF (`h:selectonemenu`) it works.

[image]

It's my first question and I speak spanish, sorry for my bad english.

I attach an image using selectonemenu with normal JSF h:selectonemenu and not PrimeFaces or BootsFaces.

Code with JSF h:selectonemenu it works but not using PrimeFaces and BootsFaces

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{pEDbean.consolidator.codigoPO}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{poaBean.listPoaSA}" var="poa1" itemLabel="#{poa1.actividad}" itemValue="#{poa1.codigopo}">
    </f:selectItems>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Option in datatable for getting value and update form where selectonemenu is

```
<p:contextMenu for="tabla1">
    <p:menuitem value=" Editar avances" icon="fa fa-edit" ajax="true" update="form1" action="#{pEDbean.obtenerupdateped()}" onclick="intermittentButton()"/>
    </p:contextMenu>
```

It's a function in beanconsolidator

```
public void obtenerupdateped() {
    try {            
        this.consolidator = consoOb;                                  
        this.comentario1 = this.consoOb.getComentario();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

With BootsFaces value's selectonemenu has to be an object and not a int or String (value="#{pEDbean.consolidator.codigoPO}")

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{pEDbean.consolidator.codigoPO}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{poaBean.listPoaSA}" var="poa1" itemLabel="#{poa1.actividad}" itemValue="#{poa1.codigopo}">
    </f:selectItems>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

I want to use PrimeFaces or BootsFaces because they have a filters in selectonemenu and more features.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to populate options of h:selectOneMenu from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-populate-options-of-hselectonemenu-from-database)

Comment: See the section "Complex object as selected item".