# Setting value in Menu and showing in Dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to set an object in `p:selectOneMenu` and show that object in a `p:dialog`.

Menu:

```
<p:form id="form1">
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.entity}" immediate="true">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.entities}" var="ent" itemLabel="#{ent.name}" itemValue="#{ent}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:commandButton value="Submit" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show();" update=":form2" />
</p:form>
```

Dialog:

```
<p:dialog header="Title" widgetVar="dlg" modal="true">
    <p:form id="form2">
        <p:outputLabel id="component" value="#{bean.entity.name}" />                        
    </p:form>
</p:dialog>
```

But unfortunately the dialog remains empty, so the entity has not been set after clicking the button. I don't get any errors.

---

When I set the entity directly in the bean, it appears in the dialog.

**Class: Bean**

```
// getter & setter

entity = entities.get(1);
```

Comment: Is this problem appears just after accessing your page and clicking the Submit button, or even after making some changes in the selectOneMenu component ?

Comment: ·@A.Henteti: I selected a value in the `selectOneMenu` and clicked the commandButton. The Dialog appears but without the just selected value in the `selectOneMenu`.

Comment: And if you run your application in development mode, you don't get any errors? And it works without a dialog?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to populate options of h:selectOneMenu from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-populate-options-of-hselectonemenu-from-database)

Comment: And please always try to create a [mcve]... it helps you narrow things down and us finding a cause. Sometimes it even helps you finding a cause or a 'duplicate' answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using custom class in your `selectOneMenu` and not simple `String`, you need custom converter.

Check out this [tutorial](https://memorynotfound.com/using-custom-converter-for-hselectonemenu/) which explains how to achieve that.

Comment: Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-populate-options-of-hselectonemenu-from-database